# ¿Cómo mover un sprite después de actualizarlo en pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Espero tengan un buen día actualmente estoy desarrollando un juego con pygame y actualmente me encuentro estancando en la parte del movimiento de los sprites,lo que llevo hasta ahorita es que se cargue el sprite estándar pero a la hora de presionar la tecla "d" para mover hacia la izquierda si carga el otro sprite pero no hace el movimiento, por favor ayúdenme llevo dos días intentando resolverlo, se los agradecería muchísimo.

```
    import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#- Funciones -
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("gab0.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey([0, 0, 0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect.move(self.rect, 420, 340)
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(220,220))
        
class Player2(pygame.sprite.DirtySprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("gaboc.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey([0, 0, 0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect.move(self.rect, 420, 340)
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(220,220))
        self.velocidad=0
    
        
#- Ventana -
pygame.display.set_caption("CCGame")
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 550])
display_rect = screen.get_rect()
bg=pygame.image.load("fondo.png").convert()

# - Sprites -
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

all_sprites.add(player)

#- Cerrar la ventana -
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
done=False

#- bucle principal -
while not done:
    
    #- moviendo el personaje -
    player2=Player2()
    tecla=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if tecla[K_d]:
        all_sprites.add(player2)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(player)
        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
    if player2.velocidad <=0:
        player2.rect.right += player2.velocidad

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
            
    #- Actualizando venta y sprites 
    all_sprites.update()
    screen.blit(bg, [0, 0])
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: El atributo velocidad del jugador 2 siempre vale 0. Estás sumandole 0 siempre a la posicion derecha del rect del jugador 2. Se entiende?

Comment: Es decir, el jugador 2 no se mueve por que su velocidad es 0

Comment: Además te doy un consejo. En lugar de hacer `if player2.velocidad <=0` podrías hacer `if player2.velocidad <0`. Notese que el primero es menor o igual a 0 y el otro es menor a 0. Para que vas a mover al jugador cuando la velocidad es 0?